# Who wrote $c = λ ν$ for the first time and where can I find it?

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength, history, speed

I have been surfing for days and still I could not find who wrote the equation $c=λν$ for the first time. Neither I found a name for this equation. A lot about Planck's constant and energy related equations, but nothing on the history of this one in particular. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Might [hsm.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: I think it goes way back when ppl were discovering the equations of the wave

Comment: You're quite right: this equation is never named or attributed to anyone. Perhaps it's thought too obvious to be attributed to an individual; anyone who understands what a wave (from a periodic source) IS can see that $v=f\lambda$. Contrast, say, Ohm's law.

Comment: Maxwell realized it as a consequence of the plane wave solutions for light if I am not mistaken, but it does not have a common attribution.

Comment: Thomas Young, around 1800, had a clear notion of wavelength and would almost certainly have known $v=f\lambda$ or its equivalent, but he may not have been the first.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle. I'll post it there. Thanks Philip, quite reasonable. Thanks Root, Matt I agree with both.